# Single choice checkboxes set in Recycler view that adds and rests points

Tags: java, android

I have a complete mindblock. I am making a simple quiz app and I want my recycler view to add points if the correct answer is selected and I want my users to have a possibility to change the answer before they click "next question". Sadly, what I wrote messes with the score every time someone changes the answer from good to bad and vice versa. I know there is some logical error, but I have no idea how to do it right.

My code from my Adapter class:

```
boolean rightAnwserSelected = false;

    if(holder.checkBox.isChecked()){
        if (mData.get(position).getIsCorrect()!=null && !rightAnwserSelected){
            rightAnwserSelected = true;
            POINTS++;
        }
    }
    if (holder.checkBox.isChecked()){
        if (mData.get(position).getIsCorrect()==null && rightAnwserSelected){
            rightAnwserSelected = false;
            POINTS--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: post complete code of adapter & activity here pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the "Next Question" button will move to another activity or such. In this case, it's probably a good idea to **not** modify the `POINTS` variable when the user makes their selection, but rather only change it in the click handler for the "Next Question" button.

All you would have to do in that case is (in the handler for the button) check which of the selections is checked and if the checked one is correct. Then you just modify the `POINTS` variable accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I decided to simplify it a lot and just stay with:

```
if(holder.checkBox.isChecked()){ 
if (mData.get(position).getIsCorrect()!=null){ 
RIGHT_ANSWER_IS_SELECTED = true; } } 
if (holder.checkBox.isChecked()){
if (mData.get(position).getIsCorrect()==null){ 
RIGHT_ANSWER_IS_SELECTED = false; } }
```

and count point in another class